# Unique constraint based on associated column value

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

I have the following (simplified) data structure:

```
Property                    Product
-----------   n <----> 1    -------
product_id                  manufacturer
type                        name
value
```

Where the products table might look like this

```
| name         |
|--------------|
| iPad 2       |
| iPhone 6     |
```

and the associated properties might be

```
| product_id | type        | value |
|----------------------------------|
|      1     | RAM         | 16GB  |
|      1     | CPU         | A11   |
|      1     | Screen Size | 10"   |
|      2     | Cellular    | yes   |
|      2     | Screen Size | 5.5"  |
```

Is it possible, in MySQL, to create a constraint, so that every product can have each property type at most once (e.g., a product can't have multiple Screen Sizes associated. As far as I could understand the MySQL docs, constraints only work on one relation, but not across relations.

Comment: Also, consider storing types in a separate table

Comment: @Strawberry true, my example isn't normalized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized the solution immediately after posting this question. The constraint can be placed on the properties relation, so that each pair of `product_id`, `type` can only exist once.